# Facebook, onActivityResult() called with requestCode=32665

Tags: android, facebook

This is a little strange.

I have an old version of the Facebook SDK built into my android app - 3.0.1

I use Facebook for authentication.

I have an onActivityResult() method in the Activity used to get the results of startActivityForResult() for an Activity that has NOTHING to do with Facebook authentication.

The weird thing that I've noticed is, if I authenticate with Facebook my onActivityResult() method gets invoked with a requestCode = 32665

I have verified my startActivityForResult() has NOT been invoked and that when it is, the request code it uses is NOT 32665

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Sorry for the external link, no time to post anything better but this should help  https://www.parse.com/questions/nullpointerexceptions-from-the-facebook-authentication

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses `onActivityResult` callback as part of it login flow, and you need to call `onActivityResult` method of one of the Facebook classes `Session` or `CallbackManager` (depends on sdks version).

So, to handle this situation, you can check whether this call from Facebook SDK or from your code by using method `isFacebookRequestCode`. Docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookSdk/#isFacebookRequestCode